# How to indicate an argument should be a reference to derived class in python typing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, typing

I would like to to pass class itself as an argument in the constructor. I know it is possible in Python but I am having problems understanding how should I write a proper typing annotation. Use case is the following:

In the constructor of class `A` I want to pass a reference to some class `X` (not an object of class `X`) that inherits after `BaseX`. Both `X` and `BaseX` come from a library. Apart from the reference to `X`, constructor of `A` accepts arguments that help build `X`:

```py
# Library
class BaseX:
    def func():
        print("Hey BaseX")

class X(BaseX):
    def func():
        print("X!")

# My client code
class A:
    def __init__(arg x, arg y, layer: BaseX): # what should be the annotation of layer?
        # construct BaseX object
        self.layer = BaseX(x=x, y=y) # IDEs show x and y as  unexpected arguments because they treat BaseX as an object and look into its __call__ func

A(5, 6, X)
```

I am unsure how can I express the annotation of layer so that it can be treated as a class and ensure its  a derivative of `BaseX`. I would also like to ask about some comment about whether this is a Pythonic way to do this.

Cheers!

Comment: Directly using class' itself look not bad but might be you cann Callable annotation which provided by *typing* module. For example, Callable[BaseX]

Comment: @Buğraİşgüzar Callable takes arguments and result types. Besides, if i'm not wrong, not every class has to be a functor.I'm not sure how does it help. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indicate that a variable is a reference to a type with the annotation `Type[BaseX]` (see [Python docs on `Type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type)). A variable annotated with `Type[T]` holds any type that is a subtype of `T`.

For your specific use case of "constructing an object of the specified type, which is a subtype of `BaseX`", you can use more accurate annotations with the help of [`TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar). For example:

```py
T = TypeVar('T', bound=BaseX)

def construct(cls: Type[T], *args, **kwargs) -> T:
    return cls(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here:

- `TypeVar('T', bound=BaseX)` defines a "type variable" that can be substituted with any type "bounded" by `BaseX`, i.e., is a subtype of `BaseX`.
- The `construct` function takes an argument `cls` with annotation `Type[T]`, indicating it's a reference to a subtype of `BaseX`.
- The return type annotation is `T`, indicating the returned value is an instance of the subtype of `BaseX`.
- All occurrences of a type variable within a function or class are bound to the same type. In this case, the type of the returned value is the type passed as argument.